# comando 'code .' não funciona nos terminais

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmd

Atualizei a versão do meu node para 20.9.0, e acredito que depois que fiz isso não consigo mais utilizar o comando 'code .'

O comando que funcionava no CMD e no powershell do VSCode, agora não funciona mais. Procurei algumas soluções e tudo que achei até agora não funcionou.

Uma das soluções é instalar a extensão Shell no VSCode, apertar F1 pra abrir o command pallet e executar o comando "Shell Command: Install 'code' commando in PATH", mas esse comando nem aparece na lista de comandos.

Alguém sabe como posso resolver isso?

inserir a descrição da imagem aqui

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Se ele não acha o executável é porque a instalação não está mais no Path do sistema.
Normalmente basta você adicionar o caminho "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Visual Studio Code"
no Path do Windows.

> O PATH é uma variável do sistema usada pelo sistema operacional para localizar executáveis necessários da linha de comandos ou da janela Terminal.
> A variável do sistema PATH pode ser definida usando o Utilitário do Sistema no painel de controle no Windows ou no arquivo de inicialização do shell no Linux e no Solaris.
> Fazer alterações na variável PATH do sistema em geral não é necessário para computadores que executam o Windows ou o Mac OS X.

https://www.java.com/pt-BR/download/help/path_pt-br.html

Para Alterar o path no Windows:
No seu caso ao invés de código Java será o comando code .

> Windows 10 e Windows 8
> Em Pesquisar, procure e selecione: Sistema (Painel de Controle)
> Clique no link Configurações avançadas do sistema.
> Clique em Variáveis de Ambiente. Na seção Variáveis do Sistema localize a variável de ambiente PATH e selecione-a. Clique em Editar. Se a variável de ambiente PATH não existir, clique em Novo.
> Na janela Editar Variável de Sistema (ou Nova Variável de Sistema), especifique o valor da variável de ambiente PATH. Clique em OK. Feche todas as janelas restantes clicando em OK.
> Reabra a janela Prompt de comando e execute o código Java.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).